# grep multiple hits in one line (bash)

Tags: bash, grep, full-text-search

I need to find multiple hits in one line (using grep/egrep). Specifically, as an example, I need to find all words surrounding the word "und" in the text "Geschehnis und Beispiel und Grund und Ursachen". But `egrep "\w+ und \w+"` has only two, not three hits:

```
 $ echo "Geschehnis und Beispiel und Grund und Ursachen" | egrep -o "\w+ und \w+"
 > Geschehnis und Beispiel
 > Grund und Ursachen
```

I also need to find "Beispiel und Grund". How can I do this?

Comment: in given example, once `Beispiel` is matched, it cannot be made to match again as part of another match.. I am fairly confident this cannot be done using egrep... not sure if it is possible with PCRE also... also, you could add another sample input with non-matching portions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the *most* intelligent of ways, but can be done in `awk`. The idea is to match the word `und` and print the word before it and next to it.

```
echo "Geschehnis und Beispiel und Grund und Ursachen" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (match($i,/^und$/)) { print prev,$i,$(i+1) }; prev=$i }}'
```

which produces an output as

```
Geschehnis und Beispiel
Beispiel und Grund
Grund und Ursachen
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ s='Geschehnis und Beispiel und Grund und Ursachen'

$ # can also use: perl -pe 's/(\w+ und )(?=(\w+) )/$1$2\n/g'
$ echo "$s" | perl -lne 'while(/\w+ und (\w+)/){print $&; s//$1/}'
Geschehnis und Beispiel
Beispiel und Grund
Grund und Ursachen
```

- `while(/\w+ und (\w+)/)` as long as input line matches this regex

  - `print $&` print the whole matched string
  - `s//$1/` replace the matched string with only the captured group `(\w+)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would have preferred it, because its shorter. But I had problems ins perl with german umlaute ([äüu]). And I wanted to search for all words surrounding "und", with upper-case letters - what in my MWE is not recogniseable.